# Sticky navigation which appears on scroll

Tags: header, navigation, sticky

I am trying to create a menu which is hidden but appears, fixed to the top, once the user begins scrolling down the page. So far I have managed to create a menu which sticks to the top upon scrolling but am stuck on how to hide this menu initially.

This is the code I am using so far:
(I am using wordpress-headway)

JQuery:

```
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
 //STICKY NAV
 var isMobile = {
 Android: function() {
 return navigator.userAgent.match(/Android/i) ? true : false;
 },
 BlackBerry: function() {
 return navigator.userAgent.match(/BlackBerry/i) ? true : false;
 },
 iOS: function() {
 return navigator.userAgent.match(/iPhone|iPad|iPod/i) ? true : false;
 },
 Windows: function() {
 return navigator.userAgent.match(/IEMobile/i) ? true : false;
 },
 any: function() {
 return (isMobile.Android() || isMobile.BlackBerry() || isMobile.iOS() || isMobile.Windows());
 }
 };
//Calculate the height of <header>
 //Use outerHeight() instead of height() if have padding
 var aboveHeight = $('.top-row').outerHeight();

 //when scroll
 $(window).scroll(function(){

 //if scrolled down more than the header’s height but this isn't mobile
 if ($(window).scrollTop() > aboveHeight && !isMobile.any()){

 // if yes, add “fixed” class to the <nav>
 // add padding top to the #content 
 // (value is same as the height of the nav)
 $('.block-type-navigation').addClass('fixed').css('top','0').next()
 .css('padding-top','42px');

 } else {

 // when scroll up or less than aboveHeight,
 // remove the “fixed” class, and the padding-top
 $('.block-type-navigation').removeClass('fixed').next()
 .css('padding-top','0');
 }
 });
});
</script>
```

CSS:

```
.fixed {
     position:fixed !important;
      left: 0;
      text-align: center;
}
.fixed .block-content {
      display: inline-block;
      text-align: left;
      width: 940px; /* This should be the width of your grid!!! */
      float:none;
}
.fixed {
position:fixed !important;    
 left: 0;      
text-align: center;
display: block !important;
}
```

It's driving me crazy so I'd appreciate ANY help!

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want the nav to show unless the user has scrolled passed a certain point then couldn't it always be fixed just off the top of the screen:

```
.menu {
    position:fixed;
    top:-42px;
}
```

then shown or hidden by toggling a class

```
.menu.is-visible {
    top:0;
}
```

using a scroll listener.

```
$win = $(window);
$win.on('scroll', function() {
    $(".menu").toggleClass('is-visible', $win.scrollTop() > 42);
});
```

You could even add some CSS animation to the `top` property

```
.menu {
    -webkit-transition: top 0.2s ease-in-out;
}
```

to get a cool transition.

Note: All this code is typed out right in here and not tested.

Note: You should definitely put a [throttle](http://underscorejs.org/#throttle) on the scroll handler too.